# How to convert 'aH bM' time format string to float?

Tags: python

I have a column in a Dataset where the time format is in 'aHrs bMin' .I need to convert this string to float value.

Example

Input = 2H 30M 
Output = 2.5

Answer (score 1):

you can make a function for that,

```
import re

def gettf(s):
  sh, sm ="0","0"
  vals= s.split(" ")
  sh = vals[0]
  if len(vals)>1:
    sm = vals[1]
  t = float(re.findall("\d+", sh)[0]) + float(re.findall("\d+", sm)[0])/60  
  return t
```

example :

```
print(gettf("5H 45M"))
```

output: 5.75

Comment: Actually the column also contains single hrs value like '2h' , '3h',... without having the 'm'(min) value.so the above code is throwing error. Please help to resolve the same too.

Comment: @vishnu accept the answer if it helped, I edited it